# Make one source set dependent on another

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I have an integration test source set in gradle, and it is dependent on my main classes being compiled. I set that up by doing

```
integrationTestClasses.dependsOn 'classes'
```

Is this the way to do it, or is there a way to setup dependencies on source sets so this happens automatically? In my `configurations` block I already have

```
integrationTestCompile { extendsFrom testCompile }
integrationTestRuntime { extendsFrom integrationTestCompile, testRuntime }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What's missing is:

```
dependencies {
    integrationTestCompile sourceSets.main.output
}
```

With this in place, task dependencies should be established automatically.

Comment: That worked, thanks. If I wanted to be dependent on both main and test output, do I just need to declare a dependency on test since test is already dependent on main? That seems to be the behavior I'm seeing but wanted to verify.

Comment: It depends on what *exactly* you mean here. `sourceSets.test.output` doesn't include `sourceSets.main.output`.

Comment: My integrationTest code has dependencies on both the test code (src/test/groovy) and main code (src/main/code).

Comment: I think my previous comment on it appearing to work that way was wrong. Looks like I need to include `sourceSets.main.output` and `sourceSets.test.output`

Comment: Yes, that's expected.

Comment: I have the same Problem, but this sollution does not seem correct, if you are working with eclipse. If anyone could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122363/gradle-sourceset-depends-on-another-sourceset that would be awesome.

Comment: This seems to cause severe problems if you try to then depend on `integrationTestCompile` configuration from a different project. For example, if in project A you have as you had described above, and then in project B you `dependencies { compile project(path: ':A', configuration: 'integrationTest' }` (after adding necessary artifacts and such to project A), gradle does not seem to know the transitive dependencies from the `compile` configuration in A (does not show up in `dependencies` or `dependencyInsight`). It adds them to the necessary classpaths but modifications cannot be made

Answer (score 4):

It is also possible to establish the dependency chain when defining the sourceSets. This worked to setup the "main" sourceSet to depend on a "generated" sourceSet:

```
// Default sourceSets already created by the java plugin: src/main and src/test
// Default content for each sourceSet: /java and /resources
sourceSets {
    // Adding src/generated
    generated
    // Setting src/main to depend on the dependencies and output of src/generated
    main {
        compileClasspath += generated.compileClasspath + generated.output
    }
}
```

The same principle should work to setup "integrationTest" to depend on "main".

Comment: Remember to also set the `runtimeClasspath`!