# Gradle sourceSet depends on another sourceSet

Tags: gradle, dependencies, source-sets

This Question is similar to [Make one source set dependent on another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140471/gradle-source-set-dependent-on-another)

Besides the main SourceSet I also have a testenv SourceSet.
The code in the testenv SourceSet references the main code, therefor I need to add the main SourceSet to the testenvCompile configuration.

```
sourceSets {
  testenv
}

dependencies {
  testenvCompile sourceSets.main
}
```

This does not work, because you cannot directly add sourceSets as dependencies. The recommended way to do this is:

```
sourceSets {
  testenv
}

dependencies {
  testenvCompile sourceSets.main.output
}
```

But this does not work correctly with eclipse, because when I clean the gradle build folder, eclipse can't compile anymore, since it depends on the gradle build.
Also if I change main code I'd have to rebuild the project in gradle for the changes to take effect in eclipse.

How do I declare the dependencies correctly?

**EDIT:**

This

```
sourceSets {
  testenv
}

dependencies {
  testenvCompile files(sourceSets.testenv.java.srcDirs, sourceSets.testenv.resources.srcDirs)
}
```

works for the main source, but because I now reference the .java files I am missing generated classes from the Annotation-Processor :(

Comment: I stumbled upon this question and experimented for hours before arriving at this article, which might resolve such cases: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So after all this is the way to go:

```
sourceSets {
  testenv
}

dependencies {
  testenvCompile sourceSets.main.output
}
```

To make it work correctly with eclipse you have to manually exclude all sourceSet outputs from the eclipse classpath.
This is ugly, but it works for me:

```
Project proj = project

eclipse {
  classpath {
    file {
      whenMerged { cp ->
        project.logger.lifecycle "[eclipse] Excluding sourceSet outputs from eclipse dependencies for project '${project.path}'"
        cp.entries.grep { it.kind == 'lib' }.each { entry ->
          rootProject.allprojects { Project project ->
            String buildDirPath = project.buildDir.path.replace('\\', '/') + '/'
            String entryPath = entry.path

            if (entryPath.startsWith(buildDirPath)) {
              cp.entries.remove entry

              if (project != proj) {
                boolean projectContainsProjectDep = false
                for (Configuration cfg : proj.configurations) {
                  boolean cfgContainsProjectDependency = cfg.allDependencies.withType(ProjectDependency).collect { it.dependencyProject }.contains(project)
                  if(cfgContainsProjectDependency) {
                    projectContainsProjectDep = true
                    break;
                  }
                }
                if (!projectContainsProjectDep) {
                  throw new GradleException("The project '${proj.path}' has a dependency to the outputs of project '${project.path}', but not to the project itself. This is not allowed because it will cause compilation in eclipse to behave differently than in gradle.")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember to also set the `runtimeClasspath`!